# width of flex card is stretched if the last row has less number of cards than other rows after using flex-grow to make cards stretch on resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

In the attached code, there is flex div that is supposed to show 2 items in small, 3 in medium and 4 in larger screen.

In the demo,  there are 8 items, so the grid will be like:

- Larger Screen: 2 rows * 4 items = 8 (OK)
- Small Screen: 4 rows * 2 items = 8 (OK)
- Medium Screen: 2 rows * 3 items = 6, 3rd row = 2 items (here comes the problem)

In the medium screen, 2 items are left for the third row and in the third row, those 2 items are stretched to take the width of 3 items.

**NOTE:**

- This snippet is the extraction of the problem I am facing on my React + Tailwind app.
- In my real code, dynamic number of items are passed and mapped inside flex div, but the above code demonstrates my exact problem.
- I used `flex-grow` property to make card grow/ shrink responsively when screen is resized until it meets a breakpoint.

**Things I already tried and problems I got**

- Removing `flex-grow`: Removing this creates a blank space on the right, I don't want it.
  [image: screenshot]
- Removing `flex-grow` on each item on flex item and add `justify-center` on flex container, It adds gap between columns.
  [image: screenshot]
- Adding `flex-grow` on each flex item seems to solve above 2 problems creating third problem (which I have mentioned above).
  [image: screenshot]

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<body>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
    <div class="bg-gray-400 flex-grow p-5 w-[45%] md:w-[30%] lg:w-[20%]">1</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 flex-grow p-5 w-[45%] md:w-[30%] lg:w-[20%]">2</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 flex-grow p-5 w-[45%] md:w-[30%] lg:w-[20%]">3</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 flex-grow p-5 w-[45%] md:w-[30%] lg:w-[20%]">4</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 flex-grow p-5 w-[45%] md:w-[30%] lg:w-[20%]">5</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 flex-grow p-5 w-[45%] md:w-[30%] lg:w-[20%]">6</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 flex-grow p-5 w-[45%] md:w-[30%] lg:w-[20%]">7</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 flex-grow p-5 w-[45%] md:w-[30%] lg:w-[20%]">8</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement in a easy and simple method by using `grid` instead of `flex` div. Have a look at this example.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<body>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-2">
    <div class="bg-gray-400 p-5 w-full">1</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 p-5 w-full">2</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 p-5 w-full">3</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 p-5 w-full">4</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 p-5 w-full">5</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 p-5 w-full">6</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 p-5 w-full">7</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 p-5 w-full">8</div>
  </div>
</body>
```